# Closed form solution of a summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

First off I have absolutely no clue what I'm doing, my notes given for this course do not explain anything and I'm not sure if I'm doing this properly so I'm looking for help and an explanation on how to solve these types of problems.

$$\sum\limits_{i=4}^{n-1}6(i-1)^2$$

Looking through notes and trying to piece things together this is what I came up with

$$6 \sum\limits_{i=4}^{n-1}(i-1)^2$$

$$6 \sum\limits_{i=3}^{n-1}i^2$$

$$6(3) \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}i^2 + (n-1)$$

$$18 \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + (n-1)$$

$$3(2n^3+n^2+2n^2+n)+(n-1)$$

$$6n^3+9n^2+4n-1$$

I'm guessing that this is completely off. Can someone explain what I'm supposed to do for these kinds of questions?

Comment: It looks completely fine to me: Manipulate the expression to get something like $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$ and then look up the formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right general idea, but the details are a bit wonky. The step

$$\sum_{i=4}^{n-1}6(i-1)^2=6\sum_{i=4}^{n-1}(i-1)^2$$

is of course fine. The idea of shifting the index so as to get $i^2$ inside the summation is also good, but you have to shift the upper limit as well. That is, as $i$ runs from $4$ through $n-1$, $i-1$ runs from $3$ through $n-2$, not through $n-1$:

$$6\sum_{i=4}^{n-1}(i-1)^2=6\sum_{i=3}^{n-2}i^2\;.$$

It’s the next step where you went rather badly astray. You want to use the formula

$$\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\;,\tag{1}$$

which is exactly what you should want to do, but you’ve not adjusted correctly for the fact that your limits of summation aren’t $1$ and $n$. Taking care of the lower limit is easy:

$$\sum_{i=3}^ni^2=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2-\left(1^2+2^2\right)=\sum_{i=1}^ni^2-5\;.$$

And taking care of the upper limit is even easier: just substitute $n-2$ for $n$ in $(1)$ to get

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=3}^{n-2}i^2&=\frac{(n-2)\big((n-2)+1\big)\big(2(n-2)+1\big)}6-5\\
&=\frac{(n-2)(n-1)(2n-3)}6-5\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=4}^{n-1}6(i-1)^2&=6\sum_{i=3}^{n-2}i^2\\
&=(n-2)(n-1)(2n-3)-30\\
&=2n^3-9n^2+13n-36\;.
\end{align*}$$